# JPA @ManyToOne Two Tables

Tags: java, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have two table Student and Student_Pseudo. 
A Pseudo can be attributed for one or more Student.

Student contains

```
* Student_code 
* Student_login
```

Student_Pseudo contains

```
* Stu_code 
* Pseudo
```

Stu_code is a foreign key of Student_code

I want to get Pseudo in Student Entity using @ManyToOne relation and it's not working

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="STU_CODE", referencedColumnName="STUDENT_CODE", nullable=false)
    private Pseudo pseudo;
```

The Pseudo is always null when I get Students !!!

Comment: Your mapping (or your description) is wrong: the join column in Student is named STUDENT_CODE, not STU_CODE. The column it references in the pseudo table is named STU_CODE, not STUDENT_CODE. Why this inconsistent naming in the first place? You're making your own life more difficult than it should be.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Tables are old in the project and I can't change them. Do you mean that I should put name="STUDENT_CODE", referencedColumnName="STU_CODE" ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: I've got an error stack by doing that.

Comment: @Samy please update your question with that error

Comment: @Lino Without Doing what JB Nizet purposed. I don't have any error.

Comment: @Samy but without it, it still doesn't work, right?

Comment: @Lino The Students are loaded correctly but the pseudo attribute is always null

Comment: It isn't clear to me what this Student_Pseudo.Pseudo is. Is it a reference? Otherwise, your JoinColunn annotation is backwards - referencedColumnName is the field in the 'other' table the 'name' field is referencing. You should be getting exceptions since "STU_CODE" doesn't exist in the Student table.  Show your Pseudo class and how you have it mapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution based on @Chris response. Thanks to everyone for your help.

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "Student_Pseudo", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STU_CODE", nullable=false), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="STU_CODE", nullable=false))
private Pseudo pseudo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's a little roundabout but its the first thing I thought of and it does work. You said you needed to fetch student pseudos so a `Set` is added in `Student` for that. It should be an `EmbeddableCollection` because I don't see you reference any primary key in student_pseudo. The foreign key is created by the parent entity and you just need to name it with `JoinColumn`. Everything else is redundant.

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id private int studentCode;
    private String studentLogin;
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=StudentPseudo.class)
    @CollectionTable(joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="stu_code")})
    private Set<StudentPseudo> pseudos = new HashSet<>();


@Embeddable
public class StudentPseudo {
    private String pseudo;
```

and maybe your problem is in fetching it.

```
tx.begin();
Student student = new Student();
student.setStudentCode(1);
StudentPseudo studentPseudo1 = new StudentPseudo();
studentPseudo1.setPseudo("ps1");
student.getPseudos().add(studentPseudo1);
StudentPseudo studentPseudo2 = new StudentPseudo();
studentPseudo2.setPseudo("ps2");
student.getPseudos().add(studentPseudo2);

em.persist(student);
tx.commit();

em.clear();

List<Student> rl = em.createQuery("select distinct s from Student s left join fetch s.pseudos", Student.class).getResultList();

System.out.println(rl.get(0) + Arrays.toString(rl.get(0).getPseudos().toArray()));
```

and that gives

```
Hibernate: select distinct student0_.studentCode as studentC1_1_, student0_.studentLogin as studentL2_1_, pseudos1_.stu_code as stu_code1_2_0__, pseudos1_.pseudo as pseudo2_2_0__ from Student student0_ left outer join Student_pseudos pseudos1_ on student0_.studentCode=pseudos1_.stu_code
model.Student@2e380628[model.StudentPseudo@2b8bd14b, model.StudentPseudo@5f13be1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. A Student can have only one Pseudo and multiple Students can have the same Pseudo. Do you think that having a collection is the solution ? The primary key in Student_pseudo is  CONSTRAINT "STUDENT_PSEUDO_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("STU_CODE", "PSEUDO")

Comment: You can do that with an Entity. You should make your question more clear about what problem you are or are not having.

Comment: What I need is for example, if I have 3 Students with student_code (1, 2, 3) respectively and student_login (St_1, St_2, St_3). Suppose that the students 1 and 2 have the same Pseudo "PST". In the table Student_pseudo, I will have two values [ Stu_code = 1, Pseudo = 'PST'] , [Stu_code = 2, Pseudo = 'PST' ]. What I need is when I load the students I want an attribut pseudo in the entity Student having the value "PST" for St_1 and St_2 and (null) for St_3

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Student_Pseudo is a relation table between Student and Pseudo, there are multiple ways to do this, but the easiest would be:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinTable(
    name = "Student_Pseudo", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PSEUDO"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="STU_CODE", referencedColumnName="STUDENT_CODE", nullable=false))
private Pseudo pseudo;
```